# How to select MS Excel version while creating excel files using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office

I am trying to export data from MS Excel 2007 to MS Excel 2016. But how can I select the version of the destination excel file to MS Excel 2016. Any clues on this?

Comment: Do you mean `*.xls` and `*.xslx`?

Comment: No no I am not talking about extensions, I am talking about to to create files version specific